# Python 3 can't use with couch db

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, couchdb-python

I am using IDE PyCharm 3.4 and python 3.3 (tried use python 3.4 but the same problem). I want to install CouchDB package through IDE:

Step by step:
1) Install "Pygments" package (because it's required package) 
2) Trying to install "CouchDB"package - 
    print 'Pygments not installed, syntax highlighting disabled'

When I am using python 2.7, I have't this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 support for couchdb-python was recently committed, but not yet included in any release. You can either wait for the next release (0.10 I guess) or install package from sources, not from PyPI as PyCharm does.

Comment: @AntonErjomin which part exactly doesn't? the latest couchdb-python release supports Python 3, my answer isn't actual anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing "Pygments" and "CouchDB" with PyCharm 3.4 and Python 3.4.1.

I received the same results that you did, however I looked further and noticed a second CouchDB package for Python called "**pycouchdb**". I installed it no problem.

I hope this helped.